# Retention policy for Communication Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, governance, retention-policy

I am looking for a way to create a retention policy for a Communication Site.

Most of the blogs have references for applying retention policy at the document level in the SharePoint site but was not able to find any documentation which provides insight on applying a policy at a Site Collection level for the Communication site.

Is it even possible? The goal is to identify the sites which are less active and then delete them after a certain period. Similar to what M365 group retention policy does.